# How to find the question with tags which i have given in interested tag(not with any other tags)

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, specific-question, tag-watching

I need to find the question which I given in interested tag and not other than any tags extactly.

**Example** : if i given java,array as my interested tags i should get only question from those tags alone, not with other tags.

Comment: You mean a question tagged with all 3 of [java] [array] [anythingelseatall] shouldn't show up?

Comment: I assume you mean (for example), having [java], [assembly] and [matlab] favourite tags and yet getting [c] questions on the front page

Comment: @Wooble : yes for both of your comments

Comment: You can ignore tags, and hide ignored tags with a setting in your user preferences. Many / most questions have a whole bunch of other tags, it doesn't make sense to me to exclude those questions. There are probably very few that just consist of some exact set of tags. If you really want, [write a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/).